# ¿Cómo adaptar el contenido dependiendo el tamaño de la pantalla?

Tags: html, css

estoy tratando de mantener el tamaño de la pantalla al achicar el tamaño responsivo de la pantalla, adjunto imágenes para que se entienda mejor

En la siguiente imagen funciona todo bien, el tamaño de la pantalla es de 425px de ancho
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al bajar de los 425px pasa esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y al seguir achicando la pantalla se sigue achicando el contenido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo hago para ajustar el contenido a pesar de seguir achicando la pantalla? Este es mi CSS con las media queryes que utilizo

```
@media (max-width : 1024px){
.header{
    height: 60px; /*achicamos el largo del header*/
}
.header .nav .logo{
    font-size: 1.563em; /*25px tamaño letra*/
    padding: 0 1.250em; /*20px de ancho*/
    line-height: 60px; /*alto de linea, logo centrado en el header*/
}
.header .nav .nav-menu{
    flex-direction: column; /*elementos del nav uno arriba de otro*/
    align-items: center; /*centramos los elementos*/
    background-color: #2c3e50; /*color del nav-menu*/
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 60px; /*posicion de 60px para que se vea el header*/
    width: 100%; /*ancho del nav-menu*/
    height: calc(100vh - 60px); /*100% - altura del nav-menu*/
    overflow-y: auto; /*cada vez que se necesite el scroll/ruedita lo añadirá*/
    padding: 1.250em 0; /*relleno arriba y abajo 20px 0 a los lados*/
    left: 100%; /*importante para mover el menu de izquierda a derecha*/
    transition: left 0.3s; /*transición */
}
.header .nav .nav-menu .nav-menu-item{
    line-height: 70px; /*alto de linea elementos nav en menu*/
}
.header .nav .nav-menu .nav-menu-item a:hover{
    background: none;
    color: #ff9800; /*color al pasar el mouse por elementos nav*/
}
.header .nav .nav-toggle{
    display: block; /*ocultamos boton menu en laptops/pc*/
}
.header .nav .nav-menu_visible{
    left: 0; /*hacemos que el menu sea invisible*/
}
.banner{
    background-position:center; /*posición de imagen de fondo*/
}
.banner .banner-text{
    font-size: 200%; /*tamaño texto del banner*/
}
.banner .banner-description{
    font-size: 170%; /*tamaño texto del banner*/
}
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 540px) and (max-device-width : 768px) {
.banner .banner-text{
    font-size: 150%; /*tamaño texto del banner*/
}
.banner .banner-description{
    font-size: 130%; /*tamaño texto del banner*/
}
}

/*Iphone 6 7 8 VERTICAL*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 414px) and (max-device-width : 540px) {
.banner .banner-text{
    font-size: 110%; /*tamaño texto del banner*/
}
.banner .banner-description{
    font-size: 100%; /*tamaño texto del banner*/
}
}

/*Pixel 2 XL - Pixel 2*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 411px) and (max-device-width : 414px) {
.banner .banner-text{
    font-size: 110%; /*tamaño texto del banner*/
}
.banner .banner-description{
    font-size: 100%; /*tamaño texto del banner*/
}
}
/*iPhone X*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 375px) and (max-device-width : 411px) {
.banner .banner-text{
    font-size: 100%; /*tamaño texto del banner*/
}
.banner .banner-description{
    font-size: 90%; /*tamaño texto del banner*/
}
}
/*Galaxy S5 - Moto G4*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 360px) and (max-device-width : 375px) {
.banner .banner-text{
    font-size: 100%; /*tamaño texto del banner*/
}
.banner .banner-description{
    font-size: 90%; /*tamaño texto del banner*/
}
}
/*Galaxy Fold*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 280px) and (max-device-width : 360px) {
.banner .banner-text{
    font-size: 80%; /*tamaño texto del banner*/
}
.banner .banner-description{
    font-size: 70%; /*tamaño texto del banner*/
}
}
```

No entiendo porque no se respetan las media query, ayuda por favor.

Comment: Hola te falta colocar el código html.

Answer (score 0):

Soy nuevo en el tema pero creo que es porque usas `min-device-width` y `max-device-width`, cuando deberias usar `min-width` y `max-width` ya que estos ultimos funcionan de acuerdo al tamaño en si del browser, o sea google.